# swift data types - coercion of Optional<Any>

Tags: swift, coercion

I have a code like so:

```
let userInfo = responseJSON.result.value as! [String : Any]
print(type(of: userInfo)) //Dictionary<String, Any>
print(type(of: userInfo["billing_addresses"]))//Optional<Any>
print(userInfo["billing_addresses"] as! [[String : AnyObject]] )
 //[["state": FL, "address_name": <null>, "city": PVD Beach, "postcode": 32082, "phone_number": 111111111, "is_default_for_billing": 1, "last_name": Rhoads, "country_code": US, "first_name": Ted, "address_line2": , "company_name": , "email_address": test6@test.com, "address_line1": 308 Sea Moss Lane]]
addNewPairToPlist(key: "billing_addresses", value: userInfo["billing_addresses"] as! [[String : AnyObject]], plistName: "UserInfo")   
// fileNotWritten
addNewPairToPlist(key: "shipping_addresses", value: userInfo["shipping_addresses"] as! [[String : AnyObject]], plistName: "UserInfo")   
//fileNotWritten



func addNewPairToPlist(key: String , value: Any?, plistName: String){
    SwiftyPlistManager.shared.addNew(value!, key: key, toPlistWithName: plistName, completion: { ( err ) in
        if err == nil {
            print("-----Value: '\(String(describing: value)) added at key: '\(key)------")
        } else {
            print(err!)
        }
    })
}
```

I'd like to add an array of objects with addresses to plists as key-value pair. Am I wrong with data types or with whole idea?)
String values have been added successfully.
There could be more than one billing/shipping address in server's response.

here is what printing out to the console:

```
[SwiftyPlistManager] Starting to add value '[["state": FL, "address_name": <null>, "city": PVD Beach, "postcode": 32082, "phone_number": 11111111, "is_default_for_billing": 1, "last_name": Rhoads, "country_code": US, "first_name": Ted, "address_line2": , "company_name": , "email_address": test6@test.com, "address_line1": 308 Sea Moss Lane]]' for key 'billing_addresses' to 'UserInfo.plist' . . .
[SwiftyPlistManager] File not written successfully
[SwiftyPlistManager] fileNotWritten
fileNotWritten
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having, is the code not working as expected and if so how is it failing?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the problem is at the commented lines(errors are printed out) - both billing and shipping addresses are not written to the plist

Comment: @JoakimDanielson updated question with what have been printed out